# core-js cannot resolve core-js/modules/es6.typed.uint32-array

Tags: babeljs, gatsby, emscripten, babel-polyfill

I recently struggled to find a solution to the below error about `core-js/modules/es6.typed.uint32-array` not being found during Webpack stage when including an C++ Emscripten-generated javascript module into a Gatsby React app in some dev-dependency environments.

Here is the example error to make it easy to Google:

```
 ERROR #98124  WEBPACK

Generating development JavaScript bundle failed

Can't resolve 'core-js/modules/es6.typed.uint32-array' in

    ERROR #98124  WEBPACK

Can't resolve 'core-js/modules/es6.typed.float32-array' in '/Users/tk/gitrepos/windfall8/src/library'

If you're trying to use a package make sure that 'core-js/modules/es6.typed.float32-array' is installed. If you're trying to use a local file make sure that the path is correct.

 ERROR #98124  WEBPACK

Can't resolve 'core-js/modules/es6.typed.float64-array' in '/Users/tk/gitrepos/windfall8/src/library'

If you're trying to use a package make sure that 'core-js/modules/es6.typed.float64-array' is installed. If you're trying to use a local file make sure that the path is correct.

 ERROR #98124  WEBPACK

Can't resolve 'core-js/modules/es6.typed.int16-array' in '/Users/tk/gitrepos/windfall8/src/library'

If you're trying to use a package make sure that 'core-js/modules/es6.typed.int16-array' is installed. If you're trying to use a local file make sure that the path is correct.

 ERROR #98124  WEBPACK

Can't resolve 'core-js/modules/es6.typed.int32-array' in '/Users/tk/gitrepos/windfall8/src/library'

If you're trying to use a package make sure that 'core-js/modules/es6.typed.int32-array' is installed. If you're trying to use a local file make sure that the path is correct.

 ERROR #98124  WEBPACK

Can't resolve 'core-js/modules/es6.typed.int8-array' in '/Users/tk/gitrepos/windfall8/src/library'

If you're trying to use a package make sure that 'core-js/modules/es6.typed.int8-array' is installed. If you're trying to use a local file make sure that the path is correct.

File: src/library/anypiajs.mjs

 ERROR #98124  WEBPACK

Can't resolve 'core-js/modules/es6.typed.uint16-array' in '/Users/tk/gitrepos/windfall8/src/library'

If you're trying to use a package make sure that 'core-js/modules/es6.typed.uint16-array' is installed. If you're trying to use a local file make sure that the path is correct.

 ERROR #98124  WEBPACK

Generating development JavaScript bundle failed

Can't resolve 'core-js/modules/es6.typed.uint32-array' in '/Users/tk/gitrepos/windfall8/src/library'

If you're trying to use a package make sure that 'core-js/modules/es6.typed.uint32-array' is installed. If you're trying to use a local file make sure that the path is correct.

 ERROR #98124  WEBPACK

Can't resolve 'core-js/modules/es6.typed.uint8-array' in '/Users/tk/gitrepos/windfall8/src/library'

If you're trying to use a package make sure that 'core-js/modules/es6.typed.uint8-array' is installed. If you're trying to use a local file make sure that the path is correct.

 ERROR #98124  WEBPACK

Can't resolve 'core-js/modules/es6.typed.uint8-clamped-array' in '/Users/tk/gitrepos/windfall8/src/library'

If you're trying to use a package make sure that 'core-js/modules/es6.typed.uint8-clamped-array' is installed. If you're trying to use a local file make sure that the path is correct.
```

Answer (score 1):

It turned out that core-js had recently changed the `.typed.` piece to `.typed-array.` from originally `core-js/modules/es6.typed.int8-array`. I just had to include these adjusted paths explicitly in my generated emscripten module.

I also `npm i core-js@3` but I didn't test if it was needed. There was no special babelrc configuration needed:

```
import 'core-js/modules/es6.typed-array.float32-array';
import 'core-js/modules/es6.typed-array.float64-array';
import 'core-js/modules/es6.typed-array.int16-array';
import 'core-js/modules/es6.typed-array.int32-array';
import 'core-js/modules/es6.typed-array.int8-array';
import 'core-js/modules/es6.typed-array.uint16-array';
import 'core-js/modules/es6.typed-array.uint32-array';
import 'core-js/modules/es6.typed-array.uint8-array';
import 'core-js/modules/es6.typed-array.uint8-clamped-array';
```